# How can I iterate through a list of proxies with Socksipy

Tags: python, sockets, proxy

For some reason I can get this to work, using single proxy everything seems fine.

```
#This works
import socks
import urllib2
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, '68.xx.193.xx', 666)
socks.wrapmodule(urllib2)
print urllib2.urlopen('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read()
```

&

```
#This doesn't
import socks
import urllib2
proxies=['68.xx.193.xx','xx.178.xx.70','98.xx.84.xx','83.xx.86.xx']
ports=[666,1080,859,910]
for i in range(len(proxies)):
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, repr(proxies[i]), ports[i])
    socks.wrapmodule(urllib2)
    print urllib2.urlopen('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zer0/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/sy/src/test.py", line 38, in <module>
    print urllib2.urlopen('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp').read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 391, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 369, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1185, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1160, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this:

```
proxies=['68.xx.193.xx','xx.178.xx.70','98.xx.84.xx','83.xx.86.xx']
ports=[666,1080,859,910]
for i in range(len(proxies)):
    print (repr(proxies[i]), ports[i])
```

You'll get

```
("'68.xx.193.xx'", 666)
("'xx.178.xx.70'", 1080)
("'98.xx.84.xx'", 859)
("'83.xx.86.xx'", 910)
```

You're adding quotes you don't want with the `repr` call, so `urllib2` thinks it's a hostname instead of an IP address. Get rid of it and you should be fine.

Comment: I think that in your example is true cause you're making a tuple in the print. See: `>>> print (repr(proxies[0]), ports[0])("'68.xx.193.xx'", 666)` but try `>>> print repr(proxies[0])
'68.xx.193.xx'`

Comment: You are missing something -- `print 'abcdefg'` doesn't print quotation marks, because there are none in the string. Your `print` does show quotation marks, because __`repr` has added them to the string__. Did you _try it_? I'm definitely right about `repr`. The tuple was just so you could see that the string was double quoted.

Comment: Well i checked it, maybe you're right, but now, the program just freezes, no errors.

Comment: you sure it freezes? Maybe it just takes a while for it to timeout if it can't connect to one of the proxies?

Comment: nope, really sure. The proxy is working fine. In the first example it took ~3secs. Something is wrong in the code...

Comment: If you can't diagnose it with `print`s, ask another question. Are you sure you should be calling `socks.wrapmodule(urllib2)` after each one? That looks like the most likely problem to me.

Comment: lol you are absolutely right, it takes like 40 seconds now, weird. Many thanks ;)